# Can't open Windows 10 built-in apps after KB3116908

Tags: windows-10, powershell, modern-ui, windows-10-v1511

After updating my W10 PC (KB3116908). All my built-in apps don't want open. I used PowerShell to reinstall them but even after rebooting my PC, they don't want open but there are ever in the Windows start menu. So I tried to uninstall all my apps and reinstall them but it doesn't work. 
Have you an idea to remove properly all windows built'in apps and reinstall it ?
Thanks

Powershell script to reinstall :

> Get-AppxPackage -allusers | foreach {Add-AppxPackage -register
>   "$($_.InstallLocation)\appxmanifest.xml" -DisableDevelopmentMode}

Powershell script to uninstall :

```
Get-AppxPackage -allusers | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Comment: this command is broken for the 1511 version. Don't use it any longer. Refresh(Reset but keep data) your WIndows 10: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10

Comment: @magicandre1981 Do you have a source for the broken command?

Comment: @doenoe a MVP documented this issue here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/i-am-not-able-to-purchase-app-in-windows-store/45a58992-8a6a-4498-9ff4-0b7e125975fc?auth=1

Comment: I've spoken with a Microsoft expert and he sayed me that it will be more simple to reinstall my w10 pc so I've done that. Thx for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after installing the KB update.

The Powershell command above says initializing but does not complete as it has in the past.

I ended up uninstalling the update and have been able to get the system to work normally again..

Right click Start Menu > Control Panel > Program and Features

Click "View Installed Updates" upper left area.

Scroll down to Microsoft Windows and right click the update and select uninstall.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by taking ownership of the following hidden folder:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps
```

Comment: Can you provide *any* more detail? At first blush there doesn't seem to be a clear connection between this and the problem.